# Excel User Form - how to date format from the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform, date-formatting

I've created an Excel User Form which requires a date to be entered (dd/mm/yy). On entering the date in to the form it show correctly when the data is added to the Excel worksheet.

[image]

But When the textbox calls the information from the spreadsheet it converts to number not date format

any help please

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello can i send you sheet to edit it please

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the format function?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    TextBox2.Value = Format(Sheets(1).Range("A1"), "DD.MM.YYYY")
End Sub
```

Comment: there is the code can u fix it